# What is the matrix representation of the linear space isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^4\cong\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Every linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces can be represented by a matrix, once bases are chosen for the domain and range spaces.

**Question**:  What is the matrix representation for the linear space isomorphism
\begin{align}
\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}&\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4\\
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}&\mapsto[a\;b\;c\;d]
\end{align}
between $\mathbb{R}^4$ and the space $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ of $2\times2$ matrices, given the standard bases of these spaces?

**Edit**:  Let's say the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ is:
$$
\bigg\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\bigg\}
$$

Comment: What is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$?  Do you order lexicographically with row first, or column first?  Or do you use another ordering?

Comment: the edit was great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a map  $V \to U$ with bases $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ and $\{u_j\}_{i=1}^n$ respectively, a matrix form is given by forming columns $[u_1 \dots u_n]$ where  $e_i \to a_{1i}u_1+ \dots a_{ni}u_n$.

In your case the map is  $e_i \to u_i$, where $u_i$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb R^4$.

This means that the matrix representation is just the identity.

Answer (score 4):

Using the (ordered) basis you provided for $\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ and the standard basis for $\Bbb R^4$, your isomorphism is given by the identity matrix! Check it out. (By the way, *most* people will denote elements of $\Bbb R^4$ by column vectors.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a short answer to my own question.

In the given basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$, we have that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}+d\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},
$$
so this matrix is just the point in the $4$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ with coordinates
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Hence, the desired linear space isomorphism is represented by the identity matrix.